# Open Search Podman pod lost network after restart Service / Container

Tags: linux, redhat, opensearch, podman

Since updating from RHEL 7 to RHEL 8, my OpenSearch Podman (POD) is showing some strange behavior that I can't explain.

the pod is running from a service file created by Podman. When I restart the service with systemctl restart  the pod seems to lose the network adapter. Only when I restart the host AND then restart the pod does everything work.

ip add befor restart service

```bash
ip add
3: cni-podman0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:68:20:67:99:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.88.19.1/25 brd 10.88.19.127 scope global cni-podman0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: veth46c6f4c5@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cni-podman0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 76:10:58:f1:2e:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns netns-eb3daca7-a755-dab1-88fc-f5572e9cfd8f
    inet6 fe80::7410:58ff:fef1:2e45/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: cni-podman1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:9a:80:3a:36:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.89.0.1/24 brd 10.89.0.255 scope global cni-podman1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::789a:80ff:fe3a:365b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: veth8751b3a8@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cni-podman1 state UP group default 
    link/ether 4a:f6:ce:ec:71:52 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns netns-43e3f22e-6668-b06f-55e3-cb8d5151f860
    inet6 fe80::48f6:ceff:feec:7152/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
7: vethfe3c34ad@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cni-podman1 state UP group default 
    link/ether b2:b9:08:96:9a:96 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns netns-ca632558-f54a-4e96-6163-accc884f8539
    inet6 fe80::b0b9:8ff:fe96:9a96/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip add after restart service

```bash
3: cni-podman0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 16:68:20:67:99:74 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.88.19.1/25 brd 10.88.19.127 scope global cni-podman0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::1468:20ff:fe67:9974/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: veth46c6f4c5@if2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue master cni-podman0 state UP group default 
    link/ether 76:10:58:f1:2e:45 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netns netns-eb3daca7-a755-dab1-88fc-f5572e9cfd8f
    inet6 fe80::7410:58ff:fef1:2e45/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: cni-podman1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 7a:9a:80:3a:36:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.89.0.1/24 brd 10.89.0.255 scope global cni-podman1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::789a:80ff:fe3a:365b/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

interface 6 and 7 is missing ..!
Podman logs do not give any indication of the problem.

does anyone have an idea what is going on here or has a tip how I get more information about the problem?

Systeminformation:

---

Host:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.8 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.8"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

Opensearch v1.3.6
podman version 4.4.1
```

Container Information:

```
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ VERSION="8.8 (Ootpa)"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ ID="rhel"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ ID_LIKE="fedora"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ VERSION_ID="8.8"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.8 (Ootpa)"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8"
[opensearch@a8f73b2ce46d ~]$ BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"
```